# Не происходит запись данных из формы Django в базу данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, django, postgresql

Не хочет записывать данные из формы в БД. При этом месседж приходит, что пост добавлен успешно.
Вот мой код:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('unpublished', 'Unpublished'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='posts_created', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='unpublished')
    anonymity = models.SmallIntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class PostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'image','anonymity')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def post_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostCreateForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            cd = post_form.cleaned_data

            post_new = post_form.save(commit=False)

            #post.user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
            post_new.user = request.user.id
            post_new.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Add post successfully')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error add your post')
    else:
        post_form = PostCreateForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request,
                  'posts/post/create.html',
                  {'section': 'posts',
                   'post_form': post_form})
```

Comment: смущает данная строка post_new.user = request.user.id . Вы же уже привязали пользователя instance=request.user

Comment: @inzem77 
Без строки post_new.user = request.user.id запись в базу данных все равно не происходит. Но все также приходит месседж  'Add post successfully'.

Comment: Я не вижу проблем, может версия джанго старая, попробуй вместо super(Post. self).save(*args,**kwargs) использовать models.Model.save(self, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: Версия Django-3.1.4. Попробовал предложенный вами вариант - не помогло.

Comment: Решение:
Убрал instance=request.user в PostCreateForm и все заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Решение: Убрал instance=request.user в PostCreateForm и все заработало!